# How to load CSS in Django templates?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm having trouble loading CSS for my Django template.

I have the following settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/css/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/css")
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

Do I need to use both `static_url` and also `staticfiles_dirs`?

urls.py is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',homefun),
)
```

views.py is

```
def homefun(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

And the parent template is base.html which loads the css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: I'm new to python/django. Loading a static content seemed so easy in PHP and in J2EE, i'm surprised after all of pythons simplicity they made this complicated.

Comment: This is just separation of concerns: Django focus on serving dynamic content, letting the webserver of your choice deal with the static ones. Sometimes, however, different apps - possibly installed in many different places - need to serve static content, so they created this staticfiles app to help with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/css")` should actually be `STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/path/to/your/css", )` (note the trailing comma — necessary because `(eggs)` evaluates to the value `eggs`, but the trailing comma forces it to evaluate to a tuple).

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` as variable in templates, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css">
```

[Official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) have a good explanation about serving static files.

You **must** set `STATIC_ROOT` variable. Using `STATICFILES_DIRS` is optional, by default Django search within `static` directories of all your apps.

Answer (score 1):

`STATIC_URL` is for the URL of your static media (for which requests the webserver will serve static media to the browser), while `STATICFILES_DIRS` is a list of folders in your machine (where the webserver will find the files to serve). AFAIK the latter must use absolute paths, not relative ones, maybe that's why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

I am converting code from `python2.7` to `python3.4` and couldn't get the static files to displaying after the conversion.

I changed `script(src='#{STATIC_URL}js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')` to `script(src='{{STATIC_URL}}js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')` and all works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

---

You need to add this to your template, I added it on line 2:

```html
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %} <!-- Line 2 -->
    
    ...
    
    {% block css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    {% endblock %}

    ...
```

> ... these dots means that there are code around,
> just to make you aware of where other code is around it.

---

Make sure that you have this in base.html, if you gonna use     `{% block css %}`

***base.html***

```html
...
<head>
    ...
    {% block css %}
    {% endblock %}
    ...
</head>
...
```

---

And in your ***settings.py*** you need this, for finding the static url:

```py
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    (BASE_DIR / 'static')
]

...
```

How do you know where to add this in settings.py?

Answer:
If using **Django 4.0** it's under

```py
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/
```

And `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` should already exist.

---

The static folder should be created in your project folder, that's where you can create in static folder a folder called css, and then in the css folder add the css files.

[image]

---

See more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Also here
[Load static files in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289719/load-static-files-in-django)