# Load static files in Django

Tags: css, django

I tried for about 2 hours to figure out why my django static files are not loading.
Here is my static files configuration in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and here is a part of my base.py:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css'%}%">
```

Here is my directory tree:

```
D:.
├───.vscode
├───blog
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───courses
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───lingua
├───main
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───pia
│   └───__pycache__
├───posts
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   ├───images
│   ├───js
│   ├───plugins
│   │   ├───easing
│   │   ├───font-awesome-4.7.0
│   │   │   ├───css
│   │   │   ├───fonts
│   │   │   ├───less
│   │   │   └───scss
│   │   ├───OwlCarousel2-2.2.1
│   │   ├───parallax-js-master
│   │   ├───progressbar
│   │   └───video-js
│   └───styles
│       └───bootstrap4
├───static_in_env
└───templates
    ├───blog
    ├───courses
    ├───main
    └───posts
```

Could you help me to figure out why the static files are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your `STATICFILES_DIR` looks wrong.

Try this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
YOURAPP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yourapp')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' 

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(YOURAPP_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Where `yourapp` is the name of your app (not your project).

Now on your template you can access them like this:

```
{% load static %}

<link src="{% static 'someFile.css' %}">
```

If you have a folder called `css` inside of your `static` folder, you can access files in that folder like this:

```
<link src="{% static 'css/someFile.css' %}">
```

Comment: raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: @tudoropran can you post an update showing your directory setup and what staticfiles you are trying to load?  In a development environment you shouldn't have to set the `STATIC_ROOT`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your code will look for your css file in the directory `static_in_env`, given by your choice of the `STATICFILES_DIRS` parameter. This list is the source, as it were, of your static files, hence add the paths to all css scripts etc. you wish to use in your project to this list. Once you invoke `collectstatic`, these files will be collected into the `STATIC_ROOT` folder (which should initially be empty) and, finally, can be accessed on the (test or prod) server through `STATIC_URL`, e. g. by your browser.

I presume you've figured it out by yourself by now, but I'd try and replace `static_in_env` by `static` in your code, since this is the parent of `styles` and `plugins` that show up in your templates. On the other hand, you may wish to create `static` and `template` subfolders for each of your apps, but that's up to you.

Btw., from my own experience: Make sure your `BASE_DIR` parameter points exactly where you want. You usually end up with two identical directories (`mysite/mysite`) when creating a project called "mysite" (the parent would contain `manage.py` and the child `settings.py`) and I always find this somewhat confusing. Could that explain the `STATIC_ROOT` error you mentioned?

It probably would do but little harm if the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) were a tad more forthcoming in that respect ;)

Answer (score 0):

use tuples for static dirs:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env'),)
```

and in base file you have mistake,
use this for second link:

```
<link href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```